# cURL Really Slow on Systems except One

Tags: linux, debian, curl

I have 3 different setups at the office.  We have a raspberry pi 4 with gigabit nat, a debian server with gigabit nat and an Unraid server.

Running a curl post command from the first 2 only uploads at about 600k.  On the unraid box the upload is over 8k.  What should I be looking at to try and determine why the speeds are so slow on the first 2?  They are all connected to the same switch and router.  Its clearly limited on the devices themselves.  Im at a loss here.

Unraid

```
root@Tower:/mnt/user/Media# curl -F file=@test3.img https://srv-file6.gofile.io/uploadFile > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 18  463M    0     0   18 85.5M      0  6855k  0:01:09  0:00:12  0:00:57 8966k
```

Pi

```
root@DietPiSR:/media# ./upload.sh test3.img
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  5  421M    0     0    5 22.9M      0  1114k  0:06:27  0:00:21  0:06:06  623k
[1]+  Stopped                 ./upload.sh test3.img
```

Debian

```
root@Server1:/media# ./upload.sh test2.img
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  5  421M    0     0    5 12.9M      0   954k  0:08:27  0:00:15  0:08:06  413k
[1]+  Stopped                 ./upload.sh test2.img
```

The ./upload.sh is the same command but in a file with a few other commands. I have also tried CLI as well instead of using the bash script with same outcome.

I have added this to my `/etc/resolv.conf` file

```
options single-request-reopen
```

My DNS is set to `8.8.8.8 and 1.0.0.1`

**My Ethtool results**
PI

```
root@DietPiSR:/media/unraid# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: gs
        Wake-on: d
        SecureOn password: 00:00:00:00:00:00
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

Unraid

```
root@Tower:/etc# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
```

My upload.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
logdir=$HOME/log/uploads
simplekey='MYAPIKEY'
toup=${1%/}
path=$(dirname $1)"/"
if [ ! -d $logdir ]; then
    mkdir -p $logdir
fi
if [[-z $toup]]; then
    echo -e "No file to upload\n\nUsage: upload <path/to/upload>"
    exit 1;
elif [[-d $toup]]; then
    type='dir'
    filename=$(echo $toup | sed "s/.*\///")'.zip'
    7z a "/tmp/$filename" "$toup" >/dev/null
elif [[ -f $toup ]]; then
    type='file'
    filename=$(echo $toup | sed "s/.*\///")
else
    echo "$toup is not valid"
    exit 1
fi
uploadname=$(echo $1 | sed "s/.*\///")
server=$(curl -s https://apiv2.gofile.io/getServer | jq -r '.data.server')
if [[ "$type" == "dir" ]]; then
    upload=($(curl -F "email=myemail@work.com" -F "file=@/tmp/$filename" https://$server.gofile.io/uploadFile | jq -r '.data.code','.data.adminCode'))
    rm "/tmp/$filename"
else
    upload=($(curl -F "email=myemail@work.com" -F "file=@$filename" https://$server.gofile.io/uploadFile | jq -r '.data.code','.data.adminCode'))
fi

if [[ -z "${upload[1]}" ]]; then
    exit 0
else
    name=\"$filename\"
    myname=$(echo $toup | sed "s/(.*//g")
    SAVEIFS=$IFS
    IFS=$'\n'
    plot=($(curl -s "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=MYAPI&t=$myname" | jq -r '.Genre,.Plot,.Year,.Runtime,.Poster'))
    IFS=$SAVEIFS
    printf "Filename: $filename\nUpload URL: https://gofile.io/d/${upload[0]}\nAdmin Code: '${upload[1]}'\n\n" | tee -a "$logdir/$filename.log"
    printf "\n" | tee -a "$logdir/$filename.log"
    printf "Name: $myname"
    link=\"https://gofile.io/d/${upload[0]}\"
    curl -s --data 'key='$simplekey'&title=Upload Ready&msg=Filename: '"$filename"$'\nDownload URL: https://gofile.io/d/'${upload[0]}$'\nAdmin Code: '${upload[1]}'&event=Uploaded' https://api.simplepush.io/send >/dev/null && echo Upload Complete
    SCRIPT_PATH="/mnt/user/discord.sh"
      eval '"$SCRIPT_PATH" --username="Gofile Upload" --color="8510795" --thumbnail="'${plot[4]}'" --footer="Your Download is Ready" --webhook-url="$WEBHOOK" --author="Gofile Upload" --description="Plot: '${plot[1]}' \nFile Name: $filename \nURL: https://gofile.io/d/'${upload[0]}$'"'
fi
```

Comment: How are your cables?

Comment: @rfmodulator Brand new cables.  All cat8.  I even thought of that and swapped them around and same result.

Comment: I would really like to see `upload.sh` on the unraid... What does `ethtool eth0` (or `dmesg | grep eth0`) say?

Comment: @rfmodulator updated with those results and file.

Comment: Is everybody using the same API credentials ...are you being throttled by the server?

Comment: So i set up a new api and same result.  Nobody has that API.  I'm lost here. It makes no sense.   I set up a VM on unraid with ubuntu and the same result as the first 2.  What could be different.

Comment: What happens if you run `curl` on the slower ones? ...and let it run a bit (btw, I would be looking at avg. speed over a period of time, but there's still an obvious spread)

Comment: Ive also run 2 instances at the same time to test this and unraid box hammers it home with over 9k and the pi still sits at around 6-700

Comment: ```root@DietPiSR:/media/unraid# speedtest
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Verizon Fios (71.184.125.234)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by KamaTera INC (New Jersey, NJ) [402.04 km]: 10.717 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 690.75 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed................................................................................................
Upload: 501.96 Mbit/s```

Comment: @rfmodulator so the file is 421MB.  On the PI it took over 10 min to up.  On the unraid it took 2min 13 seconds.

Comment: I'm assuming there are no other loads running on anything while you're testing all of this (3 kids watching different Netflix together, mom streaming Fortnite, etc.)... I'm out of ideas at the moment, maybe someone else can chime in.

Comment: Yeah I have tried this as well clean.. no clients connected other than ssh.

Comment: Just a side note about `mkdir` : you don't need to check whether a directory already exists or not when using the `-p` flag (https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html)

Comment: Are you familiar with tshark/wireshark. Normally this is the point, where I would start to dig into communication behavior.

Comment: @WinnieTigger https://hastebin.com/kaxayejini.yaml

Comment: OK, what I need to dig into this are 2 trace-files, not the summery output of tshark. One file from the fast transfer and one file from the slow transfer, so that I am able to compare the both.